# Nullpointer Exception: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.GoogleSigninAccount(getIdtoken)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I was creating a firebase authentication application.I created it using Android Studio IDE. There is no error while building or running.The application was installed successfully, but it doesn't authenticate and crashes.
It takes input options (gmail id) but when you tap on it , it crashes.What is wrong with my code?

What i've tried: I have manually added user to firebase and selected that user in application, but still it doesn't respond.

code:

```
package com.example.gpsapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "123";
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user!=null) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Homepage.class);
        startActivity(intent);}

        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button signin = this.<Button>findViewById(R.id.googlesignin);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        createRequest();
        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createRequest() {
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                    handleSignInResult(task);
            
            }

    }
    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(null);
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
            AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Homepage.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                            else

                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            //
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

But when you tap on it the app crashes giving a Runtime Exception.

ERROR DETAILS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TN91.jpg

Comment: Try to log the error message and add it to your question.

Comment: Being what Exception? Add it to your question.

Comment: Null pointer exception

Comment: Your account object is null here `account.getIdToken(), null)`.

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).